# disassembled code with optimization where does local variables kept

Tags: c, gdb, disassembly

I am new to assembler. I am looking at diff of compiled code with -g and with -O3 fiag (optimization.

In case of optimized code, disassembled code does not show that local variables are stored over stack? Is it expected, my understanding whenever we call any function, it keeps track of local variables on stack and move to next stack frame while executing next function.

Here is disassembled code for optimized version.

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004d0 <+0>:     mov    $0x1e,%eax
   0x00000000004004d5 <+5>:     retq
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disassemble foo
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x00000000004004c0 <+0>:     lea    (%rsi,%rdi,1),%eax
   0x00000000004004c3 <+3>:     retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Source Code:

```
int
foo(int a, int b) {
    int c = 0;
    c = a + b;
    return (c);
}
int
main()
{
    int z = 10;
    int y = 20;
    int ret = 0;
    ret = foo(z, y);
    return (ret);
}
```

Comment: Local variables can be kept in registers.

Comment: If you want a helpful explanation, you need to show the source code of the functions, then someone can explain how the local variables are being stored.

Comment: Here is source code.

Answer (score 3):

C has no rules about where local variables *must* live - they can live on the stack, in registers, in memory, or be totally elided.

In your example, it seems most of your local variables have been optimized out entirely. At `-O3` `gcc` will aggressively move variables into registers, remove unused variables, and skip local variables entirely if they are just incidental temporaries. For example, in your `foo`, `gcc` will optimize away `c`, and store the addition result directly in the result register `%eax`. Note that it doesn't compile `c = 0;` into the output at all, because it knows `c` is clobbered by the very next statement.

In `main`, `z` and `y` have known values when they enter `foo`, so your compiler just inlines the definition of `foo`. Constant folding and propagation reduces the `main` to simply `return 30;`, which requires no local variables at all - this is the output you see in the assembly (`0x1e` = 30).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler has noticed that `foo()` is such a simple function that it can be compiled inline. Then it saw that all the parameters are constants, so it calculated the result. So your `main()` function has been optimized into the equivalent of:

```
int main() {
    return 30;
}
```

`$0x1e` is the number `30` in hexadecimal.

And the compilation of `foo()` has removed the variable `c`, and compiled it as if it were simply:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The arguments are passed in the registers `RSI` and `RDI`, which are added, and the sum is put in `EAX` to be returned.